# Higher-Order Logic in ordinary Mathematics?

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy, higher-order-logic

Do we use the language of higher-order logic in ordinary mathematics? (If yes: Can you give some examples?) Or are we always working with first-order logic?

Comment: Maybe you are going to say that the definition of a topological space is higher-order because we quantify over sets of sets of ... individuals. But that is not what I mean with "using higher-order logic". The example "definition of topological space" can be expressed in set theory which is a first-order theory. Thus with "using higher-order logic" I do not mean quantification over sets, which is a first-order concept, but I mean "quantification over properties".

Comment: If it can be formalized, then set theory can translate this into a first-order statement in the language of set theory. Simply because we can formalize high-order logic inside set theory.

Comment: Crossposted at MO (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/218956/higher-order-logic-in-ordinary-mathematics) - please don't do that.

Comment: Despite the crossposting, I think this is a fine question for this site.

Comment: @Noah: Even if your answer you point out that it's not entirely clear what will satisfy the OP. That is the definition of "unclear". I agree it *can* be made into a reasonable question. But it's not entirely clear what that question is, and if that is in fact the question the OP wants to ask.

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is true, but I give more leeway to such questions in logic, since it often takes quite a lot of work to figure out what one means oneself. Of course, this is a subjective take, and the question could definitely be improved.

Comment: @Noah: Yes, there is preparatory work to be done. Which is why the question "does not show research effort" (which in a case of a philosophical question is exactly figuring out what you mean to ask, or at least know that anything of high order logic can be "expressed inside ZFC to first-order") and it is therefore "unclear". In any case, closing a question is not the end of the world, questions get reopened all the time.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Mostly I was arguing against the downvotes, not close votes - -2 here and -4 at MO. If the question hadn't been crossposted, I don't think it would have been voted down so heavily. And re: preparatory work, one more reason I'm charitable with logic questions is that it's much less clear *to the OP* what constitutes a clear question. I think in many questions which are unclear, the OP has still made "good faith preparation" - in the sense that their working on and thinking about it more would not lead to a clearer question. In this case maybe not, but benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's unquestionably true that we use the *language* of higher-order logic all the time in mathematics - for instance, if I write a paper in algebra and prove something by induction, my proof by induction will be phrased as a *second-order* argument.

Now, your comment suggests you're really interested in times when we use the language of higher-order logic, *and need to*. The problem is, one of the things set theory (or class theory, or . . . ) is designed to do is let us reason about higher-order objects - properties - in a first-order way. For instance, a property of natural numbers is just a *set* of natural numbers, from the point of view of set theory. So I'm not sure what you would consider a satisfying example.

---

Note that higher-order logic (with the standard semantics - so, not just first-order logic in disguise) doesn't have a notion of *proof* - in particular, the set of validities of even second-order logic is not recursively enumerable (this is a huge, huge, HUGE understatement). So as soon as we're interested in formal(izable) mathematics, we can't be talking about genuine higher-order logic anymore.

In fact, first-order logic is basically the best available for reasoning about countable objects! This is (one of) **Lindstrom's theorem**(s): there is no logic strictly stronger than first-order logic with the Lowenheim-Skolem property (any consistent sentence has a countable model) and a recursive proof procedure.

Comment: What is a proof by induction phrased as a second-order argument?  Since, as you explain after, every calculus has a FOL semantic, that argument (which you refer as second order), whatever it is, if it is based on a calculus, it has a FOL semantic, whether you think of it or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Every set of real numbers has a least upper bound.  That is a second-order statement (about the real numbers).  (The fact that it is a first-order statement in some imaginary ZFC approximation of reality is irrelevant.)

Peano's original axiom system for the natural numbers had a second-order axiom.  **Every nonempty subset of $\mathbb N$ has a least element.**  Nowadays for use in model theory, they replace this with a first-order axiom scheme, using only subsets that can be defined within a certain system.

Comment: The OP stated that he/she views quantification over sets as a first-order statement, so there is some gap between the question and this answer.

Comment: Then the OP certainly needs to explain: What is a property, and why is it not a set?